# Get css value with phantom js

Tags: javascript, css, cucumber, phantomjs

I am using Cucumber and Capybara to run some automation tests with chrome and I have an option to run them headless with phantom js

I am trying to get the `background-image` url value and can achieve this with

```
element :errorContainer, "body.error .message-container"
alert = people_form.errorContainer.native.css_value('background-image')
```

This will return the url, however this fails when running my tests using phantom js as i get

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `css_value' for #<Capybara::Poltergeist::Node tag="div">
```

How can i get the background-image url here please

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try in this way, I hope this will give you an idea:

```
page.find('div.user-image')['style'].should == 'background-image:url(/images/user_image.jpg)'
```